# Best way to filter an array of objects by Index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects like this

```
export const productArray = [

  { 
    imgUrl: images.beautifulinwhite,
    productName: "White Flowers",
    oldPrice: "$45.99",
    newPrice: "$35.99",
  },
  {
    imgUrl: images.blueandpinkjeans,
    productName: "Blue and Pink Jeans",
    oldPrice: "$57.99",
    newPrice: "$40.99",
  },
  {
    imgUrl: images.girlinyellow,
    productName: "Yellow Tshirt",
    oldPrice: "$53.99",
    newPrice: "$37.99",
  },
  {
    imgUrl: images.ladyinblack,
    productName: "Black Hoodie",
    oldPrice: "$40.99",
    newPrice: "$33.99",
  },
]
```

How do I **filter** this array to only get the first two objects? I don't want to filter them by their attributes. I want to filter using their **indexes .**

Comment: The first object in the array is: `productArray[0]` and the second is: `productArray[1]`. If you need to pull these two out into another array: `[productArray[0], productArray[1]]`. If you definitely need to use `.filter` using the index: `productArray.filter((x, idx) => idx < 2);`

Comment: If you just want first 2, why do any computations?  just do `productArray[0].smthng` and `productArray[1].smthng`

Comment: To get the first few elements you can just use array.slice(0, n), where n is the number of elements you want to get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to filter the array by index is using the `slice()` method:

```
const productArrayFiltered = productArray.slice(0, 2);
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> The `slice()` method returns a `shallow copy` of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included) where start and end represent the index of items in that array. `The original array will not be modified.`

**Side note:** it's important to remember that the method returns a new array that must be assigned to a new constant or variable.

Comment: What does the term shallow copy mean

Comment: Shallow copy is basically a term for a type of copying the data (in this case an array) in a superficial way, we also have the deep copy that will make a true copy of the data. [You can read about it here...](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-shallow-and-deep-copy-of-a-class/)

Comment: In fact, shallow copy means that if you define a new value to productArray indexed of X, the value will also change in the productArrayFiltered. So if you do productArray[0] = 20, and console.log(productArrayFiltered[0]), the printed value will be 20.